# Web scraping from a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

I've started to develop a Chrome extension to navigate and perform actions on a website. Until now the extension is able to receive a couple of parameters and check a set of radio-buttons, fill in a few inputs of a form and then submit it.

What I want to do now is to repeat the process, but I'm stuck when the page is reloaded. And I don't know how can I do to make the script react to the finish of the request.

The workflow I want to achieve is the following (is for automatically copying a certain object):

**Popup side**

Enter the number of the Master object to copy

Enter the base name of the copies (example Mod, so the I can iterate and add mod1, mod2, modn)

Enter the number of copies

**Background side**

Select master

Select standard options

Fill in inputs

Submit form

*Wait for the page to complete the request and continue to the next copy.* (here I need help)

The problem is on the repetition, the rest is taking care of. I assume that must be a way of dealing with requests. Any ideas?

By the way I'm doing it all with the extension and tabs methods of Google Chrome plus JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: Please be more specific and/or give concrete examples. Is the challenge filling forms, submitting them, waiting, and filling forms on the next page?

Comment: Yes that's the problem. I don't know how to deal with the waiting. I've already filled and submitted the form, that part works fine. But I need to wait (some times over 20 seconds) the request to be completed after the submitting, so I can start again with the task, which, by the way, I have to do a certain number of times, changin only one number in one of the fields. So I don't know how to turn the succes of the process of submitting the form into some kind of event, how to fire the next round after being completed the first

Comment: Doesn't another page load when the form has been processed? If so you could simply use [`chrome.webRequest.onCompleted`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onCompleted) to wait for the new page to finishing loading before you continue processing.

Comment: Is not another page, but the same one is reloaded.So I think it's going to work. I would definitively give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: The chrome.webRequest was the way to go. Matthew, if you want, write your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it. This way the question and the answer would be useful for someone confronting the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i´m going to answer the question myself based on Matthew Getner´s comment. The [chrome.webRequest.onCompleted](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onCompleted) was the solution to the problem. With this method I was able to wait for the request to be completed and start over with the process. And with the [messegaes methods](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) I´ve achieved the comunication between the background and the extension itself. So I finally  was able  to filled a form, send it, and repeat. This way I´ve made a kind of robot to help a co-worker with a lame repetitive task on a aged web plataform.